# Prove or disprove $ \times  \subseteq  \times  \leftrightarrow  \subseteq  \land  \subseteq $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Prove or disprove $A×B\subseteq C×D\implies A\subseteq C\land B\subseteq D$.

Would someone be willing to help me out with this? Even just an outline of how to prove it or how to get started would be helpful. I'm at a complete loss.

Comment: You'll need some extra hypothesis about non-emptiness; if $A=\emptyset$ then $B$ could be anything and yet $A \times B \subseteq C \times D$ would be true.

Comment: What happens if an element of $A$ does not belong to $C$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right to left implication is always true: Suppose $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq D$; then if $(a,b) \in A \times B$ we know that by definition $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. $A \subseteq C$ implies that also $a \in C$ and likewise, $b \in D$ and so again by definition, $(a,b) \in B \times D$, showing the inclusion.

If $A \times B \subseteq C \times D$ and $A \neq \emptyset$ and $B \neq \emptyset$ (we must assume this, or else we have trivial counterexamples), then $A \subseteq C$: let $a \in A$ arbitrary, and pick some fixed $b_0 \in B$ by non-emptyness.
Then $(a, b_0) \in A \times B$ so that the given inclusion yields $(a,b_0) \in C \times D$ so in particular, $a \in C$, showing $A \subseteq C$. From the same inclusion we can also show $B \subseteq D$ in the same way, using some fixed $a_0  \in A$ to allow us to use the inclusion of product sets...